# Find object property by type

Tags: typescript

I have interface like

```
interface A {
   a: string;
}

interface B {
   b: string;
}

export interface C {
   rnd: A;
   rnd2: B;
}
```

And I want to have function like `update<T>(setting: T)` which finds the property of type `T` in the object, which implements `interface C` and update the property found (if exists already) values with `setting` passed.

Is there a way to achieve that ? I've tried with iterating and `typeof` but the compiler returns `This condition will always return 'false' since types 'T' and 'string' has no overlap`

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative without really in-depth knowledge, which I have of JavaScript but not TypeScript, so: I very, very much doubt this information is available at runtime. TypeScript's static type checking is done at compile-time, and it emits JavaScript. As far as I'm aware, it doesn't emit further metadata that you'd need to do this.

Comment: Now, if they were classes rather than interfaces, you could use `instanceof`. But using `instanceof` is often an indicator that you need to rethink what you're doing. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One posible solution is to pass in the key name. You can have the compiler check that the key name is a valid key of `C` and that the value parameter is of the same type as the specified key in `C`:

```
interface A { a: string; }

interface B { b: string; }

export interface C { rnd: A; rnd2: B;}

let allSettings: C = {} as C
function update<K extends keyof C>(key: K, setting: C[K]) {
    allSettings[key]  = setting;
}

update("rnd", { a: "" }) // ok
update("rnd", { b: "" }) // err
update("rnd3", { b: "" }) // err
```